# CPU requiring pairs of RAM DIMMs

Tags: memory, xeon

I want to set-up a machine using 2 Intel Xeon E5-2620 CPUs and 2 16GB DIMMs.

I am now told that for both CPUs to function, I need at least 2 pairs of identical DIMMs (4 DIMMs total).

Is that true? Is the only solution that I buy 2 more memory DIMMs?

**Update:**

The manuals for the CPUs don't mention RAM. The hardware are 2 Intel Xeon E5-2620, 2 EDGE Memory 16GB (1x16GB) ECC DRX4 DDR3 PC3L10600 DIMMs (647901-B21-PE). The motherboard is a SuperMicro X9DR7-LN4F.

Comment: Its not possible for your motherboard to support 512GB of memory if the highest capacity it supports is 32GB. The most it can support is 4*32GB or 128GB. What exactly is the qustion? The motherboard manual answers this question.  I am voting to close since this is to localized, and even if its not localized, its vague and shows a complete lack of research.

Comment: That number was taken from the manufacturer's product page [here](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/xeon/c600/x9dr7-ln4f.cfm). This isn't about the motherboards. It's about the CPUs. Do the CPUs need 2 pairs of DIMMs to function (since I now have only 1 pair)? I couldn't find any resources that specifically mention the RAM configuration supported by the CPU.

Comment: The manual does not clearly states that you must install at least 4 DIMMs to make your motherboard working. However, the motherboard block diagram shows that each CPU is interfaced to it's own set of DIMM slots and the table states that for optimal performance you need to install at least 4 DIMMs. So, it might be working with 2 DIMMs but this is not a must. You can try of course, but the performance will be much different.

Comment: @ Ramhound  The MB has 16 DIMM slots according to the maual I found.  Agree OP did little research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this motherboard, each processor needs to have its own memory to operate.

From what I read in the [manual](http://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/C606_602/MNL-1336.pdf) on page 2-9, the table indicates the minimum memory for a 2 CPU installation there needs to be two pair of memory modules (one pair per CPU) and it shows which slots they need to be in.

[image]

Comment: In other words, this is clearly a constraint of the motherboard, not the cpu, and yes, you do need 4 chips (2 pairs).

Answer (score 2):

Most manuals will have specific instructions for installing RAM.    What does the manual say? If you have additional info on the exact hardware, a better answer will be possible.

Given that the manual shows clearly that each CPU has independant RAM, you will need to add RAM in each bank for each processor. Section 2-8 of the manual shows optimal config

Note that the motherboard chipset  and not the CPU will often dictate RAM install config

[SuperMicro Download](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/xeon/c600/x9dr7-ln4f.cfm)

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Motherboard make and model?

Comment: SuperMicro X9DR7-LN4F.